# Можно ли в App.vue писать функции, и правильно ли это?

Tags: vue.js

Пишу проект на Vue, и тут есть файл App.vue где я обычно импортирую компоненты которые будут рендериться. Вопрос состоит в том, можно ли, и правильно ли писать функции в `<script setup>` внутри Vue.app, условно тот же простой скрипт на рендер компонента через v-if.

Я просто всегда думал что Vue.app нужен исключительно для импорта компонентов, а функции на рендер и прочее уже внутри нужных компонентов и т.д делаются.

Хотел бы услышать советов, т.к. на Vue относительно недавно пересел.